# Can an attacker spoof AJAX / POST requests?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new to web development, so forgive me in advance.

On the site that I am designing (from scratch with LAMP on an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS), I've created an admin page where I can validate new users, posts, etc. I've created a two simple AJAX functions so that when I click a button, a post is either approved or deleted in the database.

My question is, firstly, if I have most of my admin-level PHP scripts (delete_post.php, etc.) in a public_html/php directory--is this as bad an idea as it seems? Is the only way around this to use PHP includes for these scripts and keep them in a higher directory? Can a user spoof POST requests to these scripts?

Secondly, barring the first question, I've created a few admin-level AJAX functions for managing posts and am wondering if they are also vulnerable. For example, on my admin page, I've created buttons so that I can easily verify a post or delete it from the database. The JavaScript is only included server side if the user is present on the list of admins; however, considering what I've recently learned about JavaScript injection, could a user potentially write a spoofed AJAX request of their own?

Comment: Requests can come from anywhere.  You have no way of knowing who sent a request / why.

Comment: yes. **anything** can be spoofed.

Comment: The good news for you is that the cookie/session data that you have which verifies that a user is admin will be sent with the AJAX requests, so it's really easy to see that the admin is the one sending the AJAX request, by simply doing the same checks you do for any other HTTP request in the admin area.

Comment: The fact that the JS is only included in the page contents when the user is ad admin is irrelevant because the server will still respond to requests to the AJAX endpoint URL. I.e., the only thing standing between a non-admin user and the administrative functions is a file name that can be fairly easily guessed. This is generally called "security by obscurity" and is never a good idea. Always perform authentication on the server side, at the time the request is made.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are vulnerable.  You should never consider POST requests any more secure than say a querysting, as it's just as trivial for a malicious user to edit them.  Use tokens and\or session objects to secure your data

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are tools that allows developers to test requests and ajax calls. One of them is the well known **"Postman"**.

Browsers set the **Origin** *header*, users cant override this value but a malicious user can craft a ***curl*** request that manually sets the **Origin** *header*.

My advice is not to use ***CORS***, but to use **cookies** or **OAuth** tokens for serving *protected data*.